# $G$ abelian p-group, $H\leq G$. If $p^mG\cap H=p^mH$ for all positive $m$ (1) then $nG\cap H=nH$ for $n\geq 0$ (2).

Tags: group-theory

Hi: If $n=p^m$ for some $m$ then (2) is true by (1). Let $(n,p)=1$ and $h\in H$ with $h=ng$ for some $g\in G$ and let $|g|=p^m$ (G is a p-group). There exist $s,t|sn+tp^m=1$. Then $g=sng+tp^mg=sng+0=sng=sh$ and $h=ng=n(sh)$ proving (2). Now let $n=v p^s$ with $(v,p)=1$. I proved above that $vG\cap H=vH$ and $p^sG\cap H=p^s H$. Let $h\in H$ and  $h=ng$ for some $g\in G$. I have to prove there is $h'\in H | h=nh'$. I have $h=v(p^s g)=vh_1$, for $vp^sg\in vG\cap H$. Also $h=p^s(vg)=p^s h_2$ (3). That's all I could do. The author of the title statement says it is easy to see, so he gives no proof. Any suggestion?

EDIT: (2) in the statement says $H$ is a pure subgroup of $G$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Your proof for $(v,p)=1$ can be refined to see that we even have $vH=H$.

> So if $n=vp^m$, then $nG\cap H=nG\cap vH=v(p^mG\cap H)=v(p^mH) $.

Comment: Thanks. Given $vH=H$ then $h_2$ in (3) in the OP can be written $h_2=vh_3$ and (3) is now $h=p^s vh_3=nh_3$. But your (hidden) proof is more elegant. $vH=H$: let $|h|=p^m$. Then $h= svh+tp^mh=v(sh)$.